# Заменить «Требует правки» на «Закрыт»

Tags: предложение, локализация

Понятие «Вопрос закрыт» ни у кого не вызывает вопросов.
Вопрос закрыт, а значит он бесполезный и скоро отправится в dev/null, либо с ним что-то надо сделать и его переоткроют.
Никаких неоднозначных пониманий того, что случилось с вопросом.

Какой правки требует этот вопрос?
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434838/preg-match-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82

Он исчерпан полностью. Он не требует никакой правки. И таких вопросов, которые не нуждаются в правке, но к ним присоединена эта плашка- куча. И лишь единицы вопросов закрываются для того, чтобы их отредактировали.

Можно придумывать свои термины для общепринятых понятий, дабы не быть похожими на других, но я думаю, что в данном случае это не уместно.

Comment: Согласен. [on hold] лишняя сущность. Для ТС можно добавить "у Вас есть 7 дней, чтобы исправить/переформулировать вопрос иначе он будет удален". И все. На ХК схема так и работала и тоже переоткрытий было исчезающе минимально.

Comment: Опять [on hold] война правок. Определитесь вы уже с ним наконец. По мне так это вообще маловажная деталь реализации, которая просто не стоит того чтобы ее обсуждали в 20 тредах с 40 предложенными вариантами.

Comment: Данный вопрос уже обсуждался и большинством голосов было принято обозначать именно так. Меньшинству приходится смириться.

Comment: @pavlofff я предлагаю лишь обратиться не к голосованиям, а логике. Фраза «Требует правки» не логична, потому что она противоречит истине, которая заключена в том, что вопрос не требует правки. Такая плашка ложна и вводит в заблуждение.

Comment: ReinRaus, обсуждали же, что плохой вопрос может быть спасен путем изменения формулировки. И надо мотивировать к этому людей. Поэтому "требует правки", а не "заморожен" или "закрыт".  Для  радикально оффтопичных вопросов можно сделать отдельную причину закрытия, которая сразу поставит флаг "закрыт". Это тоже обсуждали.

Comment: А я вообще не понимаю, почему вопрос [preg_match не работает](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434838/) должен быть либо закрыт, либо исправлен. Неужели на него нельзя ответить, что регулярка просто не годиться для такой задачи?

Comment: @avp: Мне кажется, с вопросом как раз всё хорошо. Вопрос: Как мне сделать A при помощи B? Ответ: при помощи B A сделать невозможно. Добрые участники могут ещё и объяснить, почему именно (или найти дубликат). Типичная [проблема XY](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/10105), кстати.

Comment: @avp " 
Всем спасибо за ответы. Я не знаю как, но утром оно заработало. Реально это же самое" ©  Алексей Саровский. Проблема не воспроизводится у него больше. Плавающий баг.

Comment: Поменял на [предложение], т.к. всё-таки явного бага здесь нет.

Answer (score 2):

Для интереса приведу статистику по плашкам.
+ там где я считаю нужной плашку «Требует правки»
- там где должна быть «Закрыт»
= там где неоднозначно, например в самой первой ссылке вопрос пустой по смыслу, но его можно подправить, хоть и смысла от этого не прибавится:

= https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435136/
+ [глюк с background-attachment](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435102/)
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435088/
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435069/
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435040/
+ [Как создать Large Text программно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435025/)
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435022/
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435007/
- [Условия OEM лицензии Windows 7/8 - кто и на какие компьютеры может устанавливать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434952/)
+ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434941/
+ [Как центрировать модальное окно по вертикали?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434868/) его скорее следует переоткрыть, но допустим он требует правки.
+ [Почему элемент меню остаётся выделенным?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434864/)
- [Подскажите как можно автоматизировать импорт текстов из уточненных интернет ресурсов и "анализировать" текст на предмет ключевых слов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434844/)
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434838/
+ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434819/
- [Как беcплатно разослать смс пользователям?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434815/)

На текущий момент это все закрытые вопросы с первых десяти страниц вопросов.

= 1
+ 6
- 9

Дальше думайте сами.
Ощутил себя врагом народа, получая минуса :-)

Comment: Наверное правильнее сделать 2 причины удаления (по сути ведь вопрос удаляется?). Одна -- требует правки, другая -- заморожен (или как там было?). И спорить уже не придется (только по существу конкретных вопросов -- жить ему или быть удаленным)

Comment: @avp: Если вопрос принципиально неспасаем, то сразу `[удалён]` (ну или `[копия]`, `[улетел на другой подсайт]`, `[нинужен патамушта ачепятка]`), а не `[заморожен]`. А если спасаем, то `[требует правки]` — лучший вариант на текущий момент.

Comment: @VladD, т.е. вместо `[заморожен]` д.б. `[удален]` (но поскольку он еще не до конца удален -- то `[удаляется]`) Реально, мне кажется, все это в 90% случаев роли не играет. Если на вопрос не отвечают, то задающий или будет долбить новыми, чуть измененными  вопросами или плюнет на все и уйдет независимо от формулировок, правил, FAQ и т.п. писанины.

Comment: @avp: Я за то, чтобы вопросы, которые _можно_ спасти, получали плашку `[требует правки]`. Пусть 5% неленивых авторов получат намёк на то, как надо. А вот вопросы, которые невозможно спасти — те сразу закрывать, чтобы не было соблазна переформулировать и задать снова через полчаса.

Comment: Статистика хорошая. Действительно, сейчас под одним статусом объединяются как вопросы, где действительно нужно добавить информации, так и полностью безнадёжные. Но нормальные, спасаемые вопросы есть в каждой категории. В дубле могут быть дополнительные ограничения, которые делают предложенные решения неприменимыми. В невоспроизводимом автор может взять и научиться воспроизводить. Редко, но бывает же такое.

Answer (score 2):

Основная задача строки статуса - в явном виде показать автору вопроса, что с его/её сообщением что-то не так. На сколько я помню (пожалуйста, поправьте, если я ошибаюсь), на сегодня, у нас есть три статуса.

1. `[копия]`.
2. `[закрыт]`.
3. `[требует правки]`.

Фактически, разница между вопросами со статусом `[закрыт]` и `[требует правки]` в том, что при внесении правки, в случает статуса `[требует правки]`, вопрос автоматически попадает в очередь проверки на повторное открытие. Если вопрос по прошествию *пяти дней* с момента назначения статуса `[требует правки]` не будет улучшен, то статус такого вопроса должен *автоматически* измениться на `[закрыт]`, согласно [статьи в справочном центре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Таким образом, используя статус `[требует правки]` по умолчанию, мы решаем три важные задачи.

1. Упрощаем модерацию. Имея два статуса, с большой вероятностью, появятся споры и сомнения о том, какой вопрос закрывать сразу, а какому дать шанс.
2. Автоматизируем процесс модерации. Вопросы автоматически попадают в очередь проверки в случае внесения улучшающей правки или закрываются по прошествию пяти дней.
3. По умолчанию, мы даем возможность каждому пользователю улучшить свой вопрос, если он по каким-либо критериям по мнению сообщества не соответствует требованиям сайта.

Comment: Николай, может быть стоит четко разделить причины закрытия и вешаемую плашку, если это возможно? Например, если вопрос закрыт как «опечатка, проблема саморастворилась», то он не требует правки, а просто должен быть «Закрыт». Аналогично с «несоответствие теме форума», «опросник», «принадлежит другому сайту стэкэсченджа».

Comment: @ReinRaus Так как закрывают (в теории, на enSO в основном) пиры, они могут ошибаться, даже пятеро за раз, посему править такие вещи скриптом - потенциально внести больше неразберихи, чес тут уже есть.