# Вопрос о проблеме, которая больше не воспроизводится, требует правки?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Наблюдая [очередной вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/989548/15479), который закрыт по причине "Больше не воспроизводится", словил себя снова на мысли, что сообщение о том, что **вопрос требует правки** совсем не к месту.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но ведь вопрос решён, правок не требуется в принципе. Это как-то можно по-другому подать?

Comment: Может так: с ответами ТС "Переустановил (винду|что-то ещё там) и заработло", флаговать вопрос на удаление "проблемы с содержанием, правка не поможет"?

Comment: @0xdb вообще, да. Подобные вопросы в принципе никому больше не помогут. Проще их удалять наверно.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [Заменить «Требует правки» на «Закрыт»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/748)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Считаю, что статус «требует правки» здесь уместен.

Различия между статусами «требует правки» и «закрыт» — чисто технические и никак не связаны с сутью проблемы и степенью завершенностью работы над вопросом. Любой вопрос, который «требует правки» через пять дней сменит статус на «закрыт». И это не означает что вопрос больше не «требует правки». И наоборот, многие вопросы, отмеченные как «требует правки» можно исправить только переписав текст с нуля, например: вопросы-ТЗ («слишком общий»), полные тексты домашних заданий и крайне непонятные вопросы.

Статус «требует правки» [придуман](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173497/every-close-has-its-thorn-replace-close-with-on-hold-for-the-first-five-d) для того чтобы побудить новичков переписывать свои закрытые вопросы и добиваться переоткрытия. Цель: показать автору, что вопрос можно отредактировать и переоткрыть ([Что означает статус вопроса «закрыт» или «требует правки»?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)):

> ... На вопрос «требующий правки» нельзя опубликовать ответ, но можно внести улучшающую правку, чтобы в дальнейшем открыть его повторно.

В данном случае автор может переписать текст вопроса частично или полностью и добиться переоткрытия.

Почему не задать новый вопрос? Потому что автор может попасть под [блокировку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans). В этом случае автору рекомендуется исправить как можно больше старых вопросов (см. [Что делать при получении сообщения «Вопросы/ответы участника с данной учётной записью больше не принимаются»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5150)):

> Перед тем как предпринять какие-либо действия, исправьте отправленные сообщения!

Переписывать вопрос полностью нехорошо, но это может быть единственный путь для открытия вопроса, улучшения рейтинга и выхода из блокировки. Если вопрос не очень популярен и не имеет ответов, то от переписывания целиком вреда никому не будет.